# You should not use <Route render> and <Route children> in the same route; <Route render> will be ignored

Tags: reactjs

```
*function LoginPainel() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter >
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' render={()=> (
        <Redirect to='/login'/>
      )} />
      <LoginRoute path='/login' component={ Login } />
    </Switch>
    <PrivateRoute path='/dashboard' >
       <div className='main-div'>
       <PrivateRoute component={ DashNavBar } />
       <Switch>
       <React.Fragment>
       <div className='dash-body'>
         <PrivateRoute exact path='/dashboard/home' component={ DashboardHome } />
         <PrivateRoute exact path='/dashboard/list-users' component={ ListUsers } />
         <PrivateRoute exact path='/dashboard/delete-users' component={ DeleteUsers } />
         <PrivateRoute exact path='/dashboard/add-users' component={ AddUsers } />
         <PrivateRoute exact path='/dashboard/update-users' component={ UpdateUsers } />
         </div>
         </React.Fragment>
       </Switch>
     </div>
     </PrivateRoute>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}*
```

I'm trying to hide all the routes from '/dashboard' forwared, but I got that ERROR.
Someone could please figure this out?